# .htaccess 301 redirection removing white space

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My site link is containing name with lots of white space in parameter.

```
file.php?dir=Songs/Bollywood%20Mp3/I%20Dont%20Luv%20U-2013
file.php?dir=Songs/Bollywood%20Mp3/Go%20Goa%20Gone-2013
file.php?dir=Songs/Bollywood%20Mp3/Hum%20Hai%20Raahi%20Car%20Ke-2103
```

Songs/Bollywood Mp3 are the directory which contain files.

I want to generate friendly url by removing white space between directory name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why dont you remove those pesky white spaces? atleast at the folder level that is in your hands right?

Comment: Hello Hanut, thanks for your reply but there are at-list thousand directory in root folder so i can not remove space manually by renaming

Comment: I guess there was no any other way. I have replaced space with underscore by running bash command. find . -depth -name '* *' \
| while IFS= read -r f ; do mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f"|tr ' ' _)" ; done